# Query help needed -- aggregates and multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, aggregate

I have several tables that are used in my application.  One maintains a list of products, another maintains comments on those items,  another contains star ratings for those items, and the last has the purchases of those items.  My tables look something like this:

```
tbl_item:
---------
id      INT (primary key)
name    VARCHAR (product name)

tbl_comment:
------------
id          INT (primary key)
item_id     INT (foregin key -> tbl_item.id)
commenttext VARCHAR

tbl_rating:
-----------
id          INT (primary key)
item_id     INT (foreign key -> tbl_item.id)
rating      DOUBLE

tbl_purchases:
--------------
id          INT (primary key)
item_id     INT (foreign key -> tbl_item.id)
```

I would like to execute a query that returns the following:

```
* The design ID
* The average rating
* The number of comments
* The number of purchases
```

I had something similar to this, but it returns the incorrect data:

```
SELECT  d.id ,
        COUNT(tbl_purchases.id) AS purchase_count, 
        COUNT(tbl_comment.id) AS comment_count,
        AVG(tbl_rating.rating) AS item_rating,
    FROM tbl_item d
    LEFT JOIN tbl_purchases ON tbl_purchases.item_id = d.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_comment ON tbl_comment.item_id = d.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_rating ON tbl_rating.id = d.id
    GROUP BY d.id;
```

What I've found is that my COUNT() columns return the same value for both columns, which is definitely not correct.  Clearly I'm doing something wrong in my joins or my GROUP BY, but I'm not entirely sure what.  I'm a Java guy, not a SQL guy, so I'm not sure what's going wrong in this SELECT statement.

Can anyone give me a hand in constructing this query?  Is there a way to perform this aggregate query across several different tables this way?  Thanks!!

Comment: The counts will come back the same because it is counting the final result set (it doesn't care if it null or not). If you want seperate counts per table, i suggest looking into sub queries.

Comment: You could also setup variables and then with a case statement manually track the totals for each table.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would accomplish this with subqueries?  Like I said, I'm a Java guy and not terribly experienced with SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  d.id ,
        COALESCE(t.purchase_count,0) as purchase_count, 
        COALESCE(c.comment_count,0) as comment_count,
        r.item_rating,
    FROM tbl_item d
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_id, COUNT(1) as purchase_count from tbl_purchases group by item_id) as t on t.item_id = d.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_id, COUNT(1) as comment_count from tbl_comment group by item_id) as c ON c.item_id = d.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_id, AVG(rating) as item_rating from tbl_rating group by item_id) as r ON r.item_id = d.id;
```

Comment: I tried @Seth Robertson's answer and it worked, but performance was terrible.  This answer worked great.  Orders of magnitude faster.  Thanks!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it is always better to implement a group by before a join, rather than after it. If you think about what the DB must do to execute a group by and a join, you will realize why this is true (I don't have enough space here to provide an explanation :)).

Answer (score 1):

Using `count(distinct(tbl_purchases.id))` should resolve your problem without the more complex queries (but also correct) queries others have offered.

Comment: I've run this query and it works great.  However, I've noticed that performance is dreadful.  Would any of the other answers result in a faster query?  Is there any way to get better performance?

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend somewhat on what db you're using, but this outta work in PostgreSQL:

```
    SELECT d.id , p.count, c.count, AVG(I.rating)
      FROM tbl_item d
      JOIN ( SELECT count(id), item_id as id from tbl_purchases ) as P
     USING (id)
      JOIN ( SELECT count(id), item_id as id from tbl_comment ) as C
     USING (id)
 LEFT JOIN tbl_rating as I
        ON tbl_rating.id = d.id
  GROUP BY d.id
;
```